# Spring boot jpa select millions of records from db and process the data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am working on a spring boot application where I need to fetch 400000 rows from db and pass it on as a list.

How should i approach this?

I am thinking of a way to split the records in groups of 1000 and pass it on.

But in that case how will I specify the offset in my sql query, like once I fetch first 1000 records how to fetch 1001 - 2000 records?

Another way is if I can fetch the records as a stream, in that case I have to find a way in which I can send the stream through a REST GET api from my application whenever someone calls my api.

Basically I need to build a rest get api where I need to pass this data to who ever is using my api

Comment: Where is the problem? A list can hold 400 000 elements, so just select the data and pass it on.

Comment: Side note: 400 000 is normally not considered "millions".

Comment: what about using [pagination](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Comment: When you say "pass it on as a list", what do you need to do with that list of items? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve in terms of input/output?

Comment: I am making an GET api which pulls and sends data to the caller, once I pull this records I need to send it over network

Comment: 400000 is not millions, its not evet million. Use limit offset - standard since 90' or earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can use OFFSET and LIMIT,
Example:
SELECT * 
FROM   t_users
ORDER BY employee_name
OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;

Now in your case, it will fetch 100 records each time, when you can pass the OFFSET value dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, it will fetch 1000 records each time, with the above query.